# EntityException in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am new to MVC and i am having a problem. I have one table named `tblEmployee` , model `Employee`. Controller `EmployeeController`. i am having EntityException in my `EmployeeController` controller.

My code for Model:

```
namespace MvcPractice.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i have created EmployeeContext.cs in Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcPractice.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext" 
                             connectionString="server=.;database=MvcDemo; integrated security=SSPI;"
                             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

[image: Exception]

[image: tblEmployee]

[image: Data in tblEmployee]

Comment: Please show your connection string (without username/password/etc of course!)

Comment: connectionString="server=.;database=MvcDemo; integrated security=SSPI;"

Comment: i am referring a video tutorial and its happening for the tutor.

Comment: and sorry but i didn't get your suggestion.

Comment: Click "View Detail" and inspect the InnerException. This will tell you what went wrong while trying to connect to the database.

Comment: {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} this is the exception in View Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a web application but you are using integrated security to connect. That will use the identity of your web application. It's preferable to use a real SQL Server user created for your application. So create a user and change your connection string to something like this:

```
server=.;database=MvcDemo;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;
```

Additionally, it's unusual for a local installation of SQL Server to be installed with an empty instance name, so you may also need to check that the server name shouldn't be this, just check what your SQL Server Management Studio is using to connect:

```
.\sqlexpress
```

Comment: AHIRE\SQLEXPRESS this is my server name. can you tell what should be my connectionstring? i have tried your solution but the same exception.

Comment: In that case it should be `server=AHIRE\SQLEXPRESS;database=MvcDemo;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;`

Comment: i am using windows authentication. so there is no user id and password. and after adding your connectionstring. exception is still coming

Comment: {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} this is the inner exception

Comment: So you have added the IIS user to your SQL Server?

Comment: Also, exceptions can be nested, so make sure you check the inner exception of the inner exception (and so on)